# Core Data: is there a way to move/copy a NSManagedObect to another context?

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I've got a NSManagedObject in Context A and would like to have it in Context B. If I use the objectID to load it in Context B, all the data in context A is lost, so I would like to copy/move the data, something like

[managedObjectInContextA copyTo:contextB];

How can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot,

Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three steps:

- early on, register somewhere appropriate for the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`. (The view controller that owns context B might be a good choice; it depends on your app architecture.)
- Make changes to context A's copy of the object, and save context A. This causes the above notification to fire.
- in the method that receives this notification, call `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` on context B. This causes context B to get in sync with the freshly saved changes.

Context B's copy of the object now has the new state.

If both copies of the object might have unsaved changes, things get more complicated. See NSManagedObjectContext's `mergePolicy` to see ways of handling that if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution would be to just save the data to the persistent store before switching contexts.

```
[managedObjectContextA save:&error];
```

Comment: but then I have to wait "some time", don't I? If I save the managedObjectContextA, then the changes are not visible in contextB immediately, are they?

Comment: They should be visible in contextB after a new fetch of course.